# How to skip waiting for winsound to end?

Tags: python

Every time winsound is played python waits until audio ends. My goal is to play sound via winsound and continue while sound is still playing. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Use multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple threads as @xihtyM mentions is not necessary. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) describes several flags for the method `winsound.PlaySound`.

The one you are looking for is:

```py
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('*', windsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

this flag let the method return immediately.